# How do I shuffle around my images in the array?

Tags: java

I'm working in Java code, but I can not figure out how to shuffle my images and text. Here is all of my coding. They are in different classes so I will post them separately. This is in Android Studio.

This is my ImageandTextAdapter code:

```
public class ImageAndTextAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private  String[] mStrings;
    private TypedArray mIcons;

    private int mViewResourceId;

    public ImageAndTextAdapter (Context ctx, int ViewResourceId, String[] strings, TypedArray icons) {
        super(ctx, ViewResourceId, strings);

     mInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     mStrings = strings;
     mIcons = icons;

     mViewResourceId = ViewResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount () { return mStrings.length; }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {return mStrings[position]; }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {return 0; }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        iv.setImageDrawable(mIcons.getDrawable(position));

        TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(mStrings[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

This is my picture array code:

```
<resources>
<array name="card_faces">
    <item>@drawable/b01</item>
    <item>@drawable/b02</item>
    <item>@drawable/b03</item>
    <item>@drawable/b04</item>
    <item>@drawable/b05</item>
    <item>@drawable/b06</item>
    <item>@drawable/b07</item>
    <item>@drawable/b08</item>

</array>
</resources>
```

This is my main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        String[] card = {"Blue1", "Blue2", "BlueSnake", "Blue4", "Blue5", "Blue6", "Blue7", "BlueHawk"};

        TypedArray card_faces = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.card_faces);

        setListAdapter(new ImageAndTextAdapter (context, R.layout.secondary_layout, card, card_faces));

    }
}
```

I want to shuffle my pictures which are set in the array, but I am not able to with the Collections.shuffle command. If you know of a way that I could shuffle my pictures using a different and simple method, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by converting the array to list and shuffle and then convert back to array

```
String[] card = {"Blue1", "Blue2", "BlueSnake", "Blue4", "Blue5", "Blue6", "Blue7", "BlueHawk"};
List<String> cardList = Arrays.asList(card);
Collections.shuffle(cardList);
cardList.toArray(card);
```

if you don't want to use more space you can try using random number generator to shuffle manually.

```
private static <T> void shuffle(T[] input){
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        swap(input, i, rand.nextInt(input.length));
    }
}
private static <T> void swap(T[] input, int x, int y){
    T tmp = input[x];
    input[x] = input[y];
    input[y] = tmp;
}
```

Edit

If you want to shuffle the images which are inside a TypedArray, Instead of shuffling the string you can simply create an array of int with index and shuffle them then use its position for both string and images.

> don't shuffle the string

```
List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++){
    indexes.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(indexes);
```

While using

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

        int newPosition = indexes.get(position);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        iv.setImageDrawable(mIcons.getDrawable(newPosition));

        TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(mStrings[newPosition]);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: What this is doing is shuffling the wording in the code. When I run my application on the device in Android Studio, I will have an image and the text next to the image. When I run this code I am shuffling my text and not my images. Any idea on how to reverse the code to shuffle my images?

Comment: @esubes21 see the updated answer